# HttpWebRequest time increases with each request for simultan requests

Tags: c#, .net, http, httpwebrequest

I got a problem with HttpWebRequest . I am trying to send out multiple requests at the same time to the same server.
When i check the timings of the response i found out that they don't take the same amount of time, instead they increase with each request.

my code so far :

```
public static void Main()
{
    ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = false;
    ServicePointManager.UseNagleAlgorithm = false;
    ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit = 1000;
    while(true)
    {
        List<Task> tasks = new List<Task>();

        for (int currency = 1; currency <= 4; currency++)
        {
            tasks.Add(Task.Factory.StartNew(async () =>
            {
                HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(string.Format("theurl"));
                request.Method = "GET";
                request.Host = "thehost";
                request.UserAgent = "Mozilla";
                request.Accept = "*/*";
                request.Headers.Add("Content-Encoding", "gzip");
                request.AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.GZip;
                request.KeepAlive = false;
                request.Proxy = null;

                long t1 = DateTime.Now.Ticks;
                var response = await request.GetResponseAsync();
                Stream receiveStream = response.GetResponseStream();
                BufferedStream buffer = new BufferedStream(receiveStream);
                StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(buffer, Encoding.UTF8);

                var result = reader.ReadToEnd();
                long t2 = DateTime.Now.Ticks;
                var whatweneed = JSON.Parse(result).At("whatweneed");
                Console.Write(whatweneed + " : ");
                Console.WriteLine((t2 - t1) / 10000.0);
            }));
        }

        Thread.Sleep(1000);
        Task.WaitAll(tasks.ToArray());
        Console.WriteLine();
    }
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

the result then looks like this:

```
whatweneed : 70.000  
whatweneed : 76.334  
whatweneed : 84.453  
whatweneed : 90.873  

whatweneed : 73.840
whatweneed : 78.294
whatweneed : 85.953
whatweneed : 92.945

whatweneed : 67.034
whatweneed : 72.452
whatweneed : 79.934
whatweneed : 88.881
```

How is that possible ??? Which concept is behind that behaviour ?

**UPDATED CODE**

```
public static void Main()
    {
    ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = false;
    ServicePointManager.UseNagleAlgorithm = false;
    ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit = 1000;
    while(true)
    {
        List<Task> tasks = new List<Task>();
        for (int value = 1; value <= 4; value++)
        {
            tasks.Add(Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
            {
                HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(string.Format("theurl"));
                request.Method = "GET";
                request.Host = "thehost";
                request.UserAgent = "Mozilla";
                request.Accept = "*/*";
                request.Headers.Add("Content-Encoding", "gzip");
                request.AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.GZip;
                request.KeepAlive = false;
                request.Proxy = null;

                using (Stream receiveStream = request.GetResponse().GetResponseStream())
                {
                    long t1 = DateTime.Now.Ticks;
                    using(BufferedStream buffer = new BufferedStream(receiveStream))
                    {
                        using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(buffer, Encoding.UTF8))
                        {
                            var result = reader.ReadToEnd();
                            long t2 = DateTime.Now.Ticks;
                            var whatweneed = JSON.Parse(result).At("whatweneed");
                            Console.Write(listing + " : ");
                            Console.WriteLine((t2 - t1) / 10000.0);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }));
        }
        Thread.Sleep(250);
        Task.WaitAll(tasks.ToArray());
        Console.WriteLine();
    }
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Result: still the same :(

**UPDATE with i=10**

```
whatweneed : 100,5859
whatweneed : 103,5156
whatweneed : 106,4453
whatweneed : 109,375
whatweneed : 112,3047
whatweneed : 116,2109
whatweneed : 119,1406
whatweneed : 121,0938
whatweneed : 101,5625
whatweneed : 101,5625

whatweneed : 107,4219
whatweneed : 111,3281
whatweneed : 113,2813
whatweneed : 117,1875
whatweneed : 120,1172
whatweneed : 123,0469
whatweneed : 126,9531
whatweneed : 128,9063
whatweneed : 92,7735
whatweneed : 92,7734
```

Looks somehow strange, that the timings raise and then with the 9th or 10th look "normal" again?
But in the main implementation i will only send 4 requests exactly at the same time, then work with them and after like 2-3 secs i will do it again.

Comment: Try putting your `IDisposible` implementations into `using` blocks: the `Stream`, `WebResponse`, etc.

Comment: Your async lambda returns prematurely to the thread-pool (at the first await). Use Task.Run. Or, just use synchronous code. Probably, you inserted the sleep because of this.

Comment: It is possible that earlier download tasks saturate your network connection with traffic, so later tasks take longer to download response.

Comment: that should not be possible - the response is a really small file and should not cause alot of traffic

Comment: Use Fiddler to see how quickly the requests were sent and received. Do the timings match what you expect? Use more than 4 requests to have more data to look at.

Comment: havnt had the time to check fiddler yet - 10 requests result above - timings should be random but all close to the same - but not going higher and higher ?

Comment: checked with fiddler - its sending out 8 requests at the same time - but then i get the results with timings above so not at the same time - couldnt find the reason behind this yet - after i got the 8 results its doing the last 2 requests